# How can I exclude some tags from `git log`?

Tags: git

I have a repository with an automated process that creates a lot of tags. Example:

```
* 5391e27 - (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Add a webhook to notify Phabricator of builds (2 hours ago) <Phil Frost>
* c380a48 - Retry downloading Selenium 3 times (2 hours ago) <Phil Frost>
| * 542731c - (tag: phabricator/diff/962) Retry downloading Selenium 3 times (6 hours ago) <Phil Frost>
|/
* 59509a3 - (tag: phabricator/base/962) Notify only on "master" branch (7 hours ago) <Phil Frost>
* 1504aa6 - Fix a few errors and omissions in README (7 hours ago) <Phil Frost>
| * a52940d - (tag: phabricator/diff/959) Notify only on "master" branch (3 days ago) <Phil Frost>
|/
| * 25838f0 - (tag: phabricator/diff/958) Notify only on "master" branch (3 days ago) <Phil Frost>
|/
* d7b3f72 - (tag: phabricator/base/959, tag: phabricator/base/958) Execute arbitrary commands in the test container (3 days ago) <Phil Frost>
```

Usually, I don't care about all these `phabricator/*/*` tags, so I'd like to see the log for all refs, *except* those. In other words, I want to see this:

```
* 5391e27 - (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Add a webhook to notify Phabricator of builds (2 hours ago) <Phil Frost>
* c380a48 - Retry downloading Selenium 3 times (2 hours ago) <Phil Frost>
* 59509a3 - Notify only on "master" branch (7 hours ago) <Phil Frost>
* 1504aa6 - Fix a few errors and omissions in README (7 hours ago) <Phil Frost>
* d7b3f72 - Execute arbitrary commands in the test container (3 days ago) <Phil Frost>
```

I'd think this would do it:

```
git log --exclude='refs/tags/phabricator/*/*' --all
```

Unfortunately, `--exclude` seems to have no effect any way I try it. How can I see all refs in the git log, except some tags that match a pattern?

Comment: Note: Git 2.16 (Q1 2018) will propose a new `--decorate-refs-exclude` option to `git log`. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47839149/6309).

Comment: With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), you also have, in addition of the `--decorate-refs-exclude` `git log` option, you *also* have now the Git **config setting** `log.excludeDecoration`. See my [(edited) answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47839149/6309).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably *should* work (and might eventually):

> `git log --exclude='refs/tags/phabricator/*/*' --all`

I think the problem is the `*/*`; try it with `--exclude='refs/tags/phabricator/*'`.  There are various places where `*` can only occur at the end of a name, and this is one of them.  (Fetch refspecs also used to be limited like this but that limitation was removed recently.)

Note that `--decorate` will still add `refs/tags/phabricator/foo/bar` to a commit that is included via `--all` that happens also to be tagged (if there are any such).  That is, the `--exclude` step keeps such commits from being *added*, but not from being *decorated* if they are already included.

Comment: You are right, the `*/*` was the problem. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 13):

As an alternative, with Git 2.16 (Q1 2018), the tagnames "`git log --decorate`" uses to annotate the commits can
now be limited to subset of available refs with the two additional options, `--decorate-refs[-exclude]=<pattern>`.

See [commit 65516f5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/65516f586b69307f977cd67cc45513a296cabc25) (21 Nov 2017) by [Rafael Ascensão (``)](https://github.com/).
Helped-by: [Kevin Daudt (`Ikke`)](https://github.com/Ikke), and [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6c3daa2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6c3daa23461333c508c41faa532c6fb749cd0db0), 13 Dec 2017)</sup>

> ### `log`: add option to choose which refs to decorate
>
> When `log --decorate` is used, git will decorate commits with all
>   available refs. While in most cases this may give the desired effect,
>   **under some conditions it can lead to excessively verbose output**.
>
> Introduce two command line options,
>
> - `--decorate-refs=<pattern>` and
> - `--decorate-refs-exclude=<pattern>`
>     to allow the user to select which refs are used in decoration.
>
> When "`--decorate-refs=<pattern>`" is given, only the refs that match the
>   pattern are used in decoration. The refs that match the pattern when
>   "`--decorate-refs-exclude=<pattern>`" is given, are never used in
>   decoration.

In your case:

```
git log -n6 --decorate=short --pretty="tformat:%f%d" \
        --decorate-refs-exclude="tags/phabricator/*"
```

---

With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), the "`--decorate-refs`" and "`--decorate-refs-exclude`" options "`git log`" takes have learned a companion configuration variable `log.excludeDecoration` that sits at the lowest priority in the family.

See [commit a6be5e6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a6be5e6764aabd4b418f7f365254518ec44c38d8), [commit c9f7a79](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9f7a793e81f517593383768ec8839dac85368c4) (16 Apr 2020) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d3fc8dc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d3fc8dc53a7ef9f33a5d9604b382e24408a9b7be), 28 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`log`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a6be5e6764aabd4b418f7f365254518ec44c38d8): add `log.excludeDecoration` config option
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
>   <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>
>
> In '`git log`', the `--decorate-refs-exclude` option appends a pattern to a `string_list`.
>   This list is used to prevent showing some refs in the decoration output, or even by `--simplify-by-decoration`.
>
> Users may want to use their refs space to store utility refs that should not appear in the decoration output. For example, **[Scalar](https://github.com/microsoft/scalar)** runs a background fetch but places the "`new`" refs inside the `refs/scalar/hidden/<remote>/*` refspace instead of `refs/<remote>/*` to avoid updating remote refs when the user is not looking.
>   However, these "hidden" refs appear during regular '`git log`' queries.
>
> A similar idea to use "hidden" refs is [under consideration for core Git](https://lore.kernel.org/git/77b1da5d3063a2404cd750adfe3bb8be9b6c497d.1585946894.git.gitgitgadget@gmail.com/).
>
> Add the '`log.excludeDecoration`' config option so users can exclude some refs from decorations by default instead of needing to use `--decorate-refs-exclude` manually.
>   The config value is multi-valued much like the command-line option.
>   The documentation is careful to point out that the config value can be overridden by the `--decorate-refs` option, even though `--decorate-refs-exclude` would always "win" over `--decorate-refs`.
>
> Since the '`log.excludeDecoration`' takes *lower* precedence to `--decorate-refs`, and `--decorate-refs-exclude` takes *higher* precedence, the struct `decoration_filter` needed another field. This led also to new logic in `load_ref_decorations()` and `ref_filter_match()`.

Answer (score 0):

`git log --oneline --format=%s -- . ":(exclude)phabricator"`

Comment: Isn't that excluding files, not refs?